# List uploaded files

Tags: php

I have som files uploaded on a server. Lets say a mixture of .jpg, .doc and .txt
I want to list these on a webpage and supply a downloadlink. Preferably using only php/html/jQuery. (ie no SQL)
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: What is the criteria for an upload to be downloadable.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a directory that stores these files you could do

```
<?php
 if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
?>
<h1>List of files:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

save that in a php file in the directory (like `index.php`), it loops through the dir and creates links to the files. `opendir('.')` looks at the current directory if your folder is somewhere else you can put the path in there.